# How to move dynamically added graphics line in winforms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am displaying two lines dynamically in form and want to move line vertically.

I tried to move using mousemove event but it's moving both lines together.

So is it possible to move dynamically added line individually on the form?

**Here is my code**

```
Graphics g;
    int Y = 250;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Form2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, new Point(0, Y), new Point(1500, Y));
        g.DrawLine(Pens.LimeGreen, new Point(0, Y+50), new Point(1500, Y+50));
    }


    public void Form2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Y = e.Location.Y;
            Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use following code to solve your purpose.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestWin
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;

            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(LineMover_Paint);
            this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(LineMover_MouseMove);
            this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(LineMover_MouseDown);
            this.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(LineMover_MouseUp);

            this.Lines = new List<GraphLine>()
            {
                new GraphLine (10, 10, 100, 200),
                new GraphLine (10, 150, 120, 40),
            };

        }
        void LineMover_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Moving != null)
            {
                this.Capture = false;
                Moving = null;
            }
            RefreshLineSelection(e.Location);

        }
        void LineMover_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshLineSelection(e.Location);
            if (this.SelectedLine != null && Moving == null)
            {
                this.Capture = true;
                Moving = new MoveInfo
                {
                    Line = this.SelectedLine,
                    StartLinePoint = SelectedLine.StartPoint,
                    EndLinePoint = SelectedLine.EndPoint,
                    StartMoveMousePoint = e.Location
                };
            }
            RefreshLineSelection(e.Location);
        }
        void LineMover_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            foreach (var line in Lines)
            {
                var color = line == SelectedLine ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
                var pen = new Pen(color, 2);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, line.StartPoint, line.EndPoint);
            }
        }
        void LineMover_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Moving != null)
            {
                Moving.Line.StartPoint = new PointF(Moving.StartLinePoint.X + e.X - Moving.StartMoveMousePoint.X, Moving.StartLinePoint.Y + e.Y - Moving.StartMoveMousePoint.Y);
                Moving.Line.EndPoint = new PointF(Moving.EndLinePoint.X + e.X - Moving.StartMoveMousePoint.X, Moving.EndLinePoint.Y + e.Y - Moving.StartMoveMousePoint.Y);
            }
            RefreshLineSelection(e.Location);
        }

        private void RefreshLineSelection(Point point)
        {
            var selectedLine = FindLineByPoint(Lines, point);
            if (selectedLine != this.SelectedLine)
            {
                this.SelectedLine = selectedLine;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
            if (Moving != null)
                this.Invalidate();

            this.Cursor =
                Moving != null ? Cursors.Hand :
                SelectedLine != null ? Cursors.SizeAll :
                  Cursors.Default;

        }
        public List<GraphLine> Lines = new List<GraphLine>();
        GraphLine SelectedLine = null;
        MoveInfo Moving = null;


        static GraphLine FindLineByPoint(List<GraphLine> lines, Point p)
        {
            var size = 10;
            var buffer = new Bitmap(size * 2, size * 2);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                //draw each line on small region around current point p and check pixel in point p 

                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
                {
                    g.Clear(Color.Black);
                    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Green, 3), line.StartPoint.X - p.X + size, line.StartPoint.Y - p.Y + size, line.EndPoint.X - p.X + size, line.EndPoint.Y - p.Y + size);
                }

                if (buffer.GetPixel(size, size).ToArgb() != Color.Black.ToArgb())
                    return line;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public class MoveInfo
        {
            public GraphLine Line;
            public PointF StartLinePoint;
            public PointF EndLinePoint;
            public Point StartMoveMousePoint;
        }
        public class GraphLine
        {
            public GraphLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
            {
                this.StartPoint = new PointF(x1, y1);
                this.EndPoint = new PointF(x2, y2);
            }
            public PointF StartPoint;
            public PointF EndPoint;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was searching thing same like this to set in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your lines take there position from the same variable Y (declared at the top of the source code) to do what you want you will need to firstly create a second variable to keep track of where the lines are individually.

Your second problem is going to be deciding which line you want to move perhaps alternating which line is moved based on which mouse button is down during Form2_MouseMove() .

Comment: is it possible to get which line is selected to move using mouse on single time using only left mouse key?

Comment: you could create another variable to store which line the mouse was closest to when the mouse button was first clicked