# Drawing a line without duplicating in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi, I would like to draw a straight line in a picturebox in winforms using mouse events. i use mouse down, mouse move and mouse up events to draw a line. However, as i move my mouse, several other lines are also being drawn. [image]

I would really appreciate if anyone can provide a guide as to how to solve this problem.

I have also attached snippets of my code for your reference. Thank you in advance!

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        mousepress = true;
        x1 = e.Location.X;
        y1= e.Location.Y;
        if (counter>0)
        {
            this.Invalidate();
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        Pen newpen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 1);



        if (mousepress)
        {
            g.DrawLine(newpen, x1, y1, e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
            x2 = e.Location.X;
            y2 = e.Location.Y;
            angle = GetAngle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
        Invalidate();


    }

  private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mousepress = false;
        double tempX=e.Location.X, tempY=e.Location.Y;

        {
            textBox_coordinates.Text = "Index: " + i + Environment.NewLine + "X: " + x2
         + Environment.NewLine + "Y: " + y2 + Environment.NewLine + "Angle: " + angle;
            i++;

        }

        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: you can store the line info in a structure and draw it after redraiwng the image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876476/how-to-move-dynamically-added-graphics-line-in-winforms

Answer (score 0):

In the MouseMove event you have to refresh the PictureBox also to clear the line(s) you have drawn in the previous call(s). And never forget to dispose the unmanaged graphics resources after allocating them, unless you want a memory hole.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // vvv take care of automatic disposal 
    using (Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics())
    using (Pen newpen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 1))
    {
        if (mousepress)
        {
            pictureBox1.Refresh(); // <-- get rid of the previous lines

            g.DrawLine(newpen, x1, y1, e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
            x2 = e.Location.X;
            y2 = e.Location.Y;
            angle = GetAngle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
        // Invalidate(); // check if necessary!
    }
}
```

Edit: Another way to get what you want is to intercept the paint event and do your line drawing there (after the inherited drawing of PictureBox). I guess most people would consider this a more clean solution because that's precisely what the paint event is for. But if you just want to get your narrow task quickly done, the solution suggested above is enough.

Comment: Did you test this? I wonder if the Invalidate makes any sense/difference?

Comment: Yes I did and it actually solved the problem (which I observed too). I have already discarded the code now, but I guess the call to Invalidate is redundant if you already call PictureBox.Refresh.

Comment: @TaW: ah, now I understand your objection, the call to Invalidate should cause another redraw which deletes even the latest user drawn lines. Hm, I'm afraid I don't know why this doesn't happen...

Comment: It does but only to the form, not its child controls. For this you would write pictureBox1.Invalidate(). Don't!   ;-) (So, please delete it from the answer!)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your help! I tried your advices but it still does not work:(

Answer (score 0):

Something like that...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool mousepressed;
    int x1=0, y1=0,x2=0,y2=0;
    Pen newPen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mousepressed = true;
        x1 = e.X;
        y1 = e.Y;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mousepressed)
        {
            x2 = e.X;
            y2 = e.Y;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }            
    }
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(newPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mousepressed = false;
    }
}
```